# Fatal error: Class 'Aerospike' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, aerospike-loader

I m try to load aerospike php api class but got error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Aerospike' not found
```

My code looks

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$config = [
    "hosts" => [
        [ "addr" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000]
    ]
];


// The new client will connect and learn the cluster layout
$db = new Aerospike($config);
```

I m doing composer install and composer update what`s wrong ? If you need more files to show tell me.

Comment: You probably need to reference the full namespace to the class.

Comment: Aerospike told : http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/php/

Comment: I suppose you installed it using composer, did you then execute the other commands?

Comment: Put this class name in autoload section of your composer.json file.

Comment: They are (_incorrectly_) using a dependency manager to [install a PHP extension](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/php/install/#build-instructions). For such a task there is [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/) and [pickle](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/pickle). You could give them a heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the Aerospike API client for PHP, you have to be able to compile C code and install the compiled extension on your server.

This requires an additional pack of installed packages than enable your machine to compile stuff, and it is way beyond the scope of Composer to provide any of these.

So this package looks innocent, but it is no genuine PHP Composer package. You cannot use it like any other package - all relevant classes like `Aerospike` are injected into PHP via the extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you have install aerospike client you don't have to  do `require "vendor/autoload.php";` it works with extension.

**First Install aerospike in any directory as [documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/php/install)**

```
git clone https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php.git
cd src/aerospike
./build.sh
```

To install the extension run inside src/aerospike:

```
make install
```

Create an aerospike.ini file at  /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d with the directive:

```
extension=aerospike.so
aerospike.udf.lua_system_path=/usr/local/aerospike/lua
aerospike.udf.lua_user_path=/usr/local/aerospike/usr-lua
```

If you are using a web server such as Apache or Nginx you will need
    to copy aerospike.ini to the configuration include directory of the
    server, then issue a graceful restart.

```
⇒  ⇒  ⇒  Verify the Extension  ⇐  ⇐  ⇐
    php -m | grep aerospike
```